# Chroma subsampling calculating bandwidth

Tags: sampling, color

How do I calculate the bandwidth required to transmit  a UHDTV signal with a frame size of 3840 x 2160 at 50fps with a sampling rate of 8bits/sample?

Answer (score 0):

Raw Byte/second for 1 byte per primary per pixel:

4:4:4 3840 x 2160 x 50 x 3

4:2:2 3840 x 2160 x 50 x 2

4:2:0 3840 x 2160 x 50 x 1.5

Comment: what of the 8bits?

Comment: Numbers are byte/second. Multiply by 8 for bits/second.